# Doubled backslashes in old posts

Tags: bug, mathjax

There is a [post from 2013](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/238/double-backslashes) addressing what appears to be a similar issue, but it is [reported as fixed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/248), so I guess it's not exactly the same.

I have noticed a few posts recently in which backslashes seem to have doubled, converting forced spacing like `\,` into line breaks like `\\,`.  I can't find most of the posts, so I'll have to content myself for now pointing to just one:  I just reviewed [an edit](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/100122/3) fixing a few instances of this.  Is this (the doubling, not the edit that fixed it) a bug?

Comment: See also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/598/list-of-recurrent-technical-problems-involving-mathjax

Comment: Ah, [@EmilJeřábek](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3162/garbled-mathjax-in-some-old-questions#comment14096_3163) points out that an automatic migration was promised but never happened, so only manual intervention is possible.  Since this seems to be a duplicate, I will close.

Comment: @jeq Let me take this opportunity to thank you for all the effort you put in manually fixing these posts.